# Scheme, can someone explain how I'm using set-car! wrong?

Tags: scheme

I wanted to make a procedure that destructively increments the odd numbers of a list. I thought I'd recurse through it and just use 'set-car!' whenever 'odd?' was true.

Here is the code:

```
   (define (test lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) lst)
        ((odd? (car lst)) (set-car! lst (+ (car lst) 1))
                            (test (cdr lst)))
        (else (test (cdr lst)))))
```

I'm not sure why it is not working, I guess I do not understand set-car! and set-cdr!
Could someone explain? Thank you.

Comment: How did you test it? What did you get? I suspect your understanding of `set-car!` is fine, but perhaps not your understanding of recursion.

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://ideone.com/d4U96Y). I second Doug's question as your problem is likely to be with how you call the function, not the function itself.

Comment: i just wrote (test '(1 2 3 4)) in the REPL. was expecting the have the list containing (2 2 4 4) returned, but all that was returned was (). When I define a list, as use that as input I can see that by calling the value of the list once more that it has been changed. I just thought it would be returned once the procedure was done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be with your interpreter, or the language in which you're defining the procedure, or the way you're calling it. For instance, in DrRacket this works fine:

```
#lang r5rs

(define (test lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) lst) ; this is the '() returned by the recursion
        ((odd? (car lst)) (set-car! lst (+ (car lst) 1))
                          (test (cdr lst)))
        (else (test (cdr lst)))))
```

Bear in mind that your procedure will return an *empty list*, because that's the base case of the recursion and this is a tail-recursive procedure, which returns the value at the base case as its final result. But don't worry, the input list was modified in-place, you can check it after the procedure returns its value.

```
(define lst (list 1 2 3 4))
(display (test lst))
=> ()
(display lst)
=> (2 2 4 4)
```

See how mutability is confusing? a procedure is returning one value, but its input was modified and has a different value now. That's one of the reasons why functional programming (which favors immutable data) is cleaner and simpler to understand, and also demonstrates why is a bad idea to mutate input parameters inside a procedure ;)

If you absolutely want the procedure to return the mutated list, do as @sepp2k suggests, but remember - the input list *was* modified and in fact, is the same list that is returned as a result:

```
(define (test lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) lst)
        ((odd? (car lst)) (set-car! lst (+ (car lst) 1))
                          (test (cdr lst))
                          lst) ; add this line
        (else (test (cdr lst)))))
```

See for yourself:

```
(define lst (list 1 2 3 4))
(display (test lst))
=> (2 2 4 4)
(display lst)
=> (2 2 4 4)
```

Comment: But say you were to write (test '(1 2 3 4)) in the REPL. The procedure would return () and not the changed list (2 2 4 4). How come?

Comment: @neo I expanded my answer to explain what's happening

Answer (score 1):

> was expecting the have the list containing (2 2 4 4) returned

The way you defined your function, it will return an empty list when called on the empty list and the result of the recursion in all other cases. So since the only base case is the empty list, you'll always return the empty list.

If you want to return the modified list, you'll need to do that after the recursion. That is after `(test (cdr lst))`, add `lst` to return the value of `lst`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `set-car!` correct. Here is how you tell it's working:

```
(define (test lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) lst)
        ((odd? (car lst)) (set-car! lst (+ (car lst) 1))
                          (test (cdr lst)))
        (else (test (cdr lst)))))

(define test-list (list 1 2 3 4))
(test test-list)
test-list ; ==> (2 2 4 4)
```

Your expectation that the function will return the modified list is wrong. To do that you need the first recursion step to return the argument. You need to wrap it:

```
(define (inc-odds lst)
  (define (test lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) lst)
          ((odd? (car lst)) (set-car! lst (+ (car lst) 1))
                            (test (cdr lst)))
          (else (test (cdr lst)))))
  (inc-odds lst) ; do the stuff
  lst)           ; return the list

(inc-odds (list 1 2 3 4)) ; ==> (2 2 4 4)
(inc-odds '(1 2 3 4)) ; ==> "pigs flying"
```

Notice the last one. In the  RNRS upto R5RS passing a quoted literal to `set-car!` would produce an undefined behaviour which means anything is ok because technically the code isn't Scheme. In R6RS it's required to raise an exception.